# Echo-ing an environment variable returns string literal rather than environment variable value

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo, fifo

I have two bash scripts. The first listens to a pipe "myfifo" for input and executes the input as a command:

```
fifo_name="myfifo"

[ -p $fifo_name ] || mkfifo $fifo_name;

while true
do
  if read line; then
    $line
  fi
done <"$fifo_name"
```

The second passes a command 'echo $SET_VAR' to the "myfifo" pipe:

```
command='echo $SET_VAR'
command_to_pass="echo $command"
$command_to_pass > myfifo
```

As you can see, I want to pass 'echo $SET_VAR' through the pipe. In the listener process, I've set a $SET_VAR environment variable. I expect the output of the command 'echo $SET_VAR' to be 'var_value,' which is the value of the environment variable SET_VAR.

Running the first (the listener) script in one bash process and then passing a command via the second in another process gives the following result:

```
$SET_VAR
```

I expected to "var_value" to be printed. Instead, the string literal $SET_VAR is printed. Why is this the case?

Comment: I used code from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900873/write-and-read-from-a-fifo-from-two-different-script

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You should read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), then rethink your question.

Comment: the risky cmd `eval` might help, but you don't include code that has set `var_value` (that I can see). Please update your Q with copy/pasteable test code. (don't make us guess how you are doing it). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I get to the problem you're reporting, I have to point out that your loop won't work. The `while true` part (without a `break` somewhere in the loop) will run forever. It'll read the first line from the file, loop, try to read a second line (which fails), loop again, try to read a third line (also fails), loop again, try to read a fourth line, etc... You want the loop to exit as soon as the `read` command fails, so use this:

```
while read line
do
    # something I'll get to
done <"$fifo_name"
```

The other problem you're having is that the shell expands variables (i.e. replaces `$var` with the value of the variable `var`) *partway through* the process of parsing a command line, and when it's done that it doesn't go back and re-do the earlier parsing steps. In particular, if the variable's value included something like `$SET_VAR` it doesn't go back and expand that, since it's just finished the bit where it expands variables. In fact, the only thing it does with the expanded value is split it into "words" (based on whitespace), and expand any filename wildcards it finds -- no variable expansions happen, no quote or escape interpretation, etc.

One possible solution is to tell the shell to run the parsing process *twice*, with the `eval` command:

```
while read line
do
    eval "$line"
done <"$fifo_name"
```

(Note that I used double-quotes around `"$line"` -- this prevents the word splitting and wildcard expansion I mentioned from happening *before* `eval` goes through the normal parsing process. If you think of your original code half-parsing the command in `$line`, without double-quotes it gets *one and a half-parsed*, which is weird. Double-quotes suppress that half-parsing stage, so the contents of the variable get parsed exactly once.)

However, this solution comes with a big warning, because `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet. `eval` makes it easy to do complex things without quite understanding what's going on, which means you tend to get scripts that work great in testing, then fail incomprehensibly later. And in my experience, when `eval` looks like the best solution, it probably means you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

So, what're you actually trying to do? If you're just trying to execute the lines coming from the fifo as shell commands, then you can use `bash "$fifo_name"` to run them in a subshell, or `source "$fifo_name"` to run them in the current shell.

BTW, the script that feeds the fifo:

```
command='echo $SET_VAR'
command_to_pass="echo $command"
$command_to_pass > myfifo
```

Is also a disaster waiting to happen. Putting commands in variables doesn't work very well in the shell (I second chepner's recommendation of [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)), and putting a command *to print another command* in a variable is just begging for trouble.

Comment: eval doesn't seem to do what you suggest it does. $SET_VAR remains a literal after eval is executed (on my machine).

Comment: @nickackerman42 That's very strange; it works for me. Try putting `set -x` just before the `while read` loop, and it'll print the commands (with a "+" prefix) just before it executes them. In my test, it prints "+ read line", "+ eval 'echo $SET_VAR'", "++ echo This is the set_var value", "This is the set_var value" (the `echo` output), and finally "+ read line" (which fails, exiting the loop and the script).

Answer (score 1):

`bash`, by it's nature, reads commands from `stdin`. You can simply run:

```
bash < myfifo
```