# Daemonize process in Linux bash

Tags: linux, daemon, systemd

What is the most convenient way to interact with a rust library that needs to keep track of some internal state in the background.

For instance I have the following program:

```rust
use tokio::io::AsyncBufReadExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut state = 0;

    let mut reader = tokio::io::BufReader::new(tokio::io::stdin());

    loop {
        let mut buffer = Vec::new();
        reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).await.unwrap();
        let cmd = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap();

        match cmd {
            "get-count\n" => {
                println!("{}", state);
                state += 1;
            }
            _ => {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

which I can interact with in the following way using Linux bash:

```
cargo run
get-count
0
get-count
1
another-command
get-count
2
```

However, this creates a blocking process and I need to use inputs from other bash commands when interacting with the library.

My goal is to run this as a daemon process in such a way that I can interact with it in the following way using bash:

```
>> ./start-service
>> ./service-cli get-count
0
>>  ./service-cli get-count
1
>> COUNT=$(./service-cli get-count)
>> echo $COUNT
2
```

What is the best practice for this when using Linux? Are there any examples of how to do something like this using systemd?

Comment: Just run it in the background? Probably set named pipes as its stdin/stdout to interact with it easily as well, otherwise it's going to be difficult. This has nothing to do with rust tho, it's really more of a job control / shell / bash question.

Comment: Yes, this question is really about how the flow would work in bash. I could perhaps redirect the program input/output to some named pipe `mypipe` and run it with `cargo run &` so I could then interact with the given PID (as long as the OS does not terminate it). So issuing commands would be `"get-count" > mypipe` and reading the corresponding command output would be `COUNT=$(cat ./mypipe)` with some way of "awaiting" for the count to be present in `mypipe`.

Comment: What you'd have to do is first create a pair of named pipes, then run your binary in the background (using `&`) but redirecting stdin and stdout to the named pipes created for that purpose. Then you can "echo" content into the stdin pipe, and `read` (using the `read` shell builtin) content back out of the stdout one. `cat` would not work because it reads until eof. See [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900873/write-and-read-from-a-fifo-from-two-different-script) for examples of fifo interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coproc` to execute the desired command with the standard output and standard input of the command connected via a pipe file descriptor.

```
coproc cargo run
```

then

```
echo get-count  >&"${COPROC[1]}"
```

and

```
read -u "${COPROC[0]}" count
echo "$count"
```